# View JSON as a list in an angular app

Tags: angular, model-view-controller

How can I show single JSON data in my browser?

app.components.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service';
import { Employee } from './employee';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  employees: Employee[];

  constructor(private _httpService: Http, private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEmployees();
  }

  getEmployees(): void {

    this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    this.employeeService.getEmployees()
      .subscribe(employees => this.employees = employees);
  }
}
```

employee.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Employee } from './employee';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, private _httpService: Http) { }

  employees: Employee[];

  getEmployees(): Observable<any> {

    console.log(this.http.get('/api/values'));

    return this.http.get('/api/values')
      .map(response => response);//.json());
    //.catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(
    //    { message: error.json().message, details: error.json().details }));
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>Application says what?</h1>
<ul>
  {{employees}}
</ul>
```

employee.ts

```
export class Employee {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Now I just get an result like this:

> [ { "id": "1", "name": "Karl" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Fritz" } ]

But I would like to show (and later handle) my employees with single output und input field. I am a bloody beginner. Sorry for this basic question. May someone wants to help me. Thanks in forward!!

I tried this, but it wasn't working:

```
<li *ngFor="let emp of employees">
    <p>{{emp.id}}</p>
    <p>{{emp.name}}</p>
</li>
```

Comment: It did not work for you?

Comment: no. should it? was it the right way?
> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[\r\n  {\r\n    \"id\": \"1\",\r\n    \"name\": \"Karl\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"id\": 2,\r\n    \"name\": \"Fritz\"\r\n  }\r\n]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: I guess Employees is coming as string to HTML file. try employees => this.employees = employees.json() ,also print the response of your webservice in console and see how it's coming

Comment: Good idea, but I get the error: "TypeError: employees.json is not a function". If I put it behind response in the service.ts I get this info: "Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[

  {

    "id": "1",

    "name": "Karl"

  },

  {

    "id": 2,

    "name": "Fritz"

  }

]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
Stack trace:"

Comment: new info: i checked my web-api and yes, it was just a string instead of a json. now i deliver a real json and still get an error like this: "error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Fritz'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays." at my getEmployees() function in the app.components.ts

Comment: what is your response from API? can you show us the format which you are getting it

Comment: You are not receiving the data in arrays so only you are getting error like this.

Comment: http://localhost:4200/api/values shows: {"id":1,"name":"Fritz"}
How can I parse it to arrays?

Comment: Everything is working fine with my code, but I made a mistake with my api-controller. See what I changed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368613/add-entity-to-json-in-mvc-controller - THANKS FOR HELPING!

Answer (score 0):

We can show json object format in proper way by using json pipe. **for example-**

```
component.ts->
obj = {
    a : 12,
    b : 123
  };

component.html
{{obj | json }}
```

[More Details](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe#example)