# Add entity to json in mvc controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I would like to add an mock entity of my model to an existing json as a new entity. In this code example: how can I add **model2** to **js**?

```
public JsonResult Get()
    {
      Employee model1 = new Employee();
      Employee model2 = new Employee();

      model1.id = 1;
      model1.name = "Fritz";
      model2.id = 2;
      model2.name = "Emil";

      JsonResult js = new JsonResult(model1);

      return js;
    }
```

Comment: So you want to send 2 Employee objects  ? like an array ?

Comment: Yes! Can you show me how I have to do this. Maybe I am doing it in a completely wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list/array of `Employee` objects and add your 2 objects (model1 and model2) to that list and send the list.

```
public JsonResult Get()
{
    var model1 = new Employee();        
    model1.id = 1;
    model1.name = "Fritz";

    var model2 = new Employee();
    model2.id = 2;
    model2.name = "Emil";

    var list= new List<Employee> { vmodel1, model2 };
    return Json(list);
}
```

If this action method is HttpGet type, you should explicitly specify that when calling the `Json` method by using the `JsonRequestBehavior` enum.

```
return Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This will return a response like below. An array of two items.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Fritz"},{"id":2,"name":"Emil"}]
```

I also suggest you to use PascalCasing for the [class property names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions). `Id` and `Name` instead of `id` and `Name`

Answer (score 0):

You can add model2 into the result as follows.

```
JsonResult js = new JsonResult(new { Model1 = model1, Model2 = model2 });
```